# Can't set several objects as angular constants

Tags: angularjs

Constants in angularjs are cool, but when I tried to put 2 objects into the same constant, I've got an error:
***Cannot read property 'property1' of undefined***.
Here is the part of my code:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .constant('CONST', {
        constantOne: {
            'property1': 'text1',
            'property2': 'text2'
        },
        constantTwo: {
            'property3': 'text3',
            'property4': 'text4'
        }
    })
```

And in my controller something like that:

```
var items: {
  oldProperty: 'property1',
}    
items.newProperty1 = CONST.constantOne[items.oldProperty];
items.newProperty2 = CONST.constantTwo[items.oldProperty];
```

But when I separated this objects to 2 different constants, everything is OK.
So, is it possible to use two objects in the same constant? I feel that I just made a syntax mistake, but I can't find where is it.

**P. S.** If it does matter, I use this constants for mapping inside my controller

## Thanks for any help

Comment: error "Cannot read property 'screening' of undefined":  there doesn't seem to be any property `screening` in the posted code.

Comment: Claies, sorry, I didn't post all information needed, i'll improve the answer in several minutes

Comment: Can you lease check my answer?

Comment: @Jigar7521 i'm trying, but still get the same result. may be the issue somewhere else. i'll keep trying and will say if I'll find the decision

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, where is `oldPropertyOne' of items defined?

Comment: the problem is only with the second constant, when I swap them, I get the same issue with another constant

Comment: @Nikhil, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('testController', ['$scope', 'CONST',
    function($scope, CONST) {

      var items = {
        field1: 'property1',
        field2: 'property2'
      }
      items.newProperty1 = CONST.constantOne[items.field1];
      items.newProperty2 = CONST.constantTwo[items.field2];
      console.log(items);
    }
  ]).constant('CONST', {
    constantOne: {
      'property1': 'text1',
      'property2': 'text2'
    },
    constantTwo: {
      'property3': 'text3',
      'property4': 'text4'
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">


</body>

</html>
```

But where is `items.oldPropertyOne` defined?

Comment: corrected, sorry for my dirty code. all of this is in my working code, i just wrote the dirty example

Comment: in your snippet the is the same result, "newProperty1" was mapped and "newProperty2" wasn't. but why?

Comment: and the most important question: how to map both of this properties?

Comment: `constantTwo` in `CONST` doesnt have a value` property2` which is coming from items.field2. Thats why it is `undefined`.

Comment: `items.newProperty2 = CONST.constantTwo[items.oldProperty];`
in this code items.oldProperty = property1

Comment: and in your CONST there is no property1
`constantTwo: {
            'property3': 'text3',
            'property4': 'text4'
        }`

Answer (score 1):

You can define even constant like this also :

```
angular
.module('myApp')
    .constant('CONST', (function () {
        return {
            constantOne: {
                'property1': 'text1',
                'property2': 'text2'
            },
            constantTwo: {
                'property3': 'text3',
                'property4': 'text4'
            }
        };
 }))
```